# Tesseract Fatal error encountered!" == NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file globaloc.cpp, line 75

Tags: java, tesseract

1 - I downloaded tesdata on the git hub https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

2 - Extract the folder and passed the path to the Tesseract class

3 - When running the application the following error is displayed

Extract the folder and passed the path to the Tesseract class

When running the application the following error is displayed

***Code snippet executed***

```
public class TesseractOcrTest {
  private final String tesseractPath = "/home/tessdata/";
  
  @Test
  public void shouldReturnTrueIfRunOcrEquals() throws Exception {
    String result = new TesseractOcr(tesseractPath).runOcr("bw_HighResolution_en.jpeg").trim();
    assertEquals(
        "Optical Character Recognition in Java\nis made easy with the help of Tesseract", result);
  }
}
```

***Error***

```
Error: Illegal Parameter specification!
"Fatal error encountered!" == NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file globaloc.cpp, line 75
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f52a582d69b, pid=8957, tid=8966
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.7+10) (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.so.4+0x25969b]  ERRCODE::error(char const*, TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x16b
```

Note: When I change the path from tesdata to the OS installation path (`private final String tesseractPath = "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/";`) I can do it perfectly. It just doesn't work if I point to the tesdata downloaded from the git hub.

What am I doing wrong? When downloaded from github do you need to do any more configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably used incompatible language data. For the current Tesseract verion, use `tessdata_best` or `tessdata_fast`, which comes with Linux distros. (You can verify by checking the file size.)

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

Comment: Your suggestion is misleading: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata are compatible current Tesseract version (includes LSMT and legacy models) e.g. also with  tessdata_best (Only LSTM model - float version) or tessdata_fast (only LSTM model - int version).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed only one version of tesseract
2. Fist check with version of tesseract you used (installed). Use the latest version (4.x or 5 alpha)
3. Test OCR with tesseract executable instead of wrapper - it can provide more information for finding problem.